# Altorouter router->map() is not working as expected

Tags: php, rest, altorouter

```
$router->setBasePath('/ecommerce/public');
$router->map( 'GET', '/', '', 'about_us' );
$match = $router->match();
```

is working just fine when I reloaded index.php page. var_dump($match) displayed the expected result;

However,

```
$router->map( 'GET', '/about', '', 'about_us' )
```

is not working when I typed localhost/about. the browser displayed "Object Not Found" error.

I suspected that maybe my root directory was not set correctly, so I also put the follow above $router->map()

```
$router->setBasePath('/ecommerce/public');
```

Unfortunately, setBasePath was not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any rewrite rule in your .htaccess?

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```